# Codeigniter and Typeaheadjs - problems

Tags: codeigniter-2, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have some problems with CI and Typeahead, I dont get any result ;/

JS

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {
    url: base_url + 'home/search?q=%QUERY',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
    }
  }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: countries.ttAdapter()
});
```

CI Controller

```
public function search(){
    $query = $this->home_model->getData();
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

CI Model

```
private $_cityTable = 'city';

public function getData(){
    $city = $this->input->get('q');
    $query = $this->db->select('city_name')->like('city_name', $city, 'after')->get($this->_cityTable);
    foreach ($query->result_array as $key) {
        $array[] = $key['city_name'];
    }
    return $array;
}
```

And view

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead">
```

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: nope ;/ if i set local array in bloodhound, typeahead works fine, i think that problem is in controller or model, but i don`t have any idea where ;/

Comment: Is your base URL local or remote? If it's remote I think you'll need to use 'remote' instead of 'prefetch'

Comment: its local, it`s vhost http://app.local.

Comment: If you look at the network traffic (e.g. use the "Network" tab in Chrome's debug tools) when you load the page, can you see the results being sent to the browser as expected?

Comment: Thx. I`ve got response from server (['item1', 'item2, ...]) but i can`t pass it into suggestion div ;/

Comment: Hi, yours answer`s was very helpfull but I give up. I don`t know what was wrong, i get responses from server but i can`t pass it into the view ;/

Comment: What errors were you getting in the browser debug console?

Comment: I don`t work with it anymore. But I think I will try again in next project so I will need your help once more :) :D

Comment: Sorry you couldn't get it working. I'll keep an eye out for other questions you may have in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

When I debugged [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/5ND8W/) example, I found that the parsedResponse object passed into the filter function has the following structure:

```
parsedResponse ={page: x, results:[], total_pages:x, total_results: x};
```

Where 'x' is an integer.

Hence to get your code to work change your filter function so that you iterate through the results array which is within the list object i.e.

```
filter: function(list) {
 return $.map(list.results, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
}
```